# can we use both typescript and javascript both in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to React. I had a doubt can we use both typescript and JS in React APP.
Existing APP is in vanilla JS. Will it be better to transform completely to TS or write only new code in TS.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Possible to write all new code in TS but highly recommend migrating everything over to Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

All JS code is a valid TS code, so you can incrementally refactor old code & use TS for all the new code.

Comment: As long as it's in a JS file, otherwise you need to dismiss the warnings of implicit any